# How to do cumsum based on column condition?

Tags: python, pandas, cumsum

I am trying to do a cumsum grouped by the name for the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( columns = ['Name','Status']) 
df['Name'] = ['Anton','Anton','Anton','Anton','Bev','Bev','Bev','Bev','Chad','Chad','Chad','Chad']
df['Status'] =[1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1] 
df
```

The first instance for each name should start at 1 and it should only sum thereafter if the status column is equal to 1, if not the value should carry over in order to give the additional column as follows:

```
df['Expected Result'] = [1,2,3,4,1,2,2,3,1,1,1,2]
df
```

I have tried doing a groupby on name and using the cumsum()+1 function but I am not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: I believe your expected results dataframe is wrong. Anyway, try: `df1 = df.groupby(['Name'])['Status'].apply(lambda x: x.cumsum())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `transform` to adjust

```
df.groupby('Name')['Status'].cumsum() + 1-df.groupby('Name')['Status'].transform('first')
Out[8]: 
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     3
8     1
9     1
10    2
11    3
Name: Status, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
df['Expected Result'] = df.groupby('Name').cumsum()
df
```

produces

```
    Name    Status  Expected Result
0   Anton   1   1
1   Anton   1   2
2   Anton   1   3
3   Anton   1   4
4   Bev     1   1
5   Bev     1   2
6   Bev     0   2
7   Bev     1   3
8   Chad    0   0
9   Chad    0   0
10  Chad    1   1
11  Chad    1   2
```

Comment: The issue is I want the Expected Result to start from 1 for each name regardless if the first instance is a 0 or 1.

Comment: @Quincy it seems what I got matches the expected result in your question so perhaps you want to clarify your question and give the expected output you are looking for?

Comment: I've made the necessary edits my apologies for the poorly phrased question

Answer (score 0):

have you tried df.groupby(['Name']).cumsum() ?
this is the result:

```
    Status
0        1
1        2
2        3
3        1
4        1
5        2
6        2
7        3
8        0
9        0
10       1
11       2
```